# Running nutch comands from a seperate server?

Tags: http, nutch

I have two servers, one of which is running my main program and another which is running nutch. I would like to be able to programmatically configure/trigger nutch runs from the main program using http requests i.e. automatically send commands to nutch from a different server with http. Is this possible using the CLI or do I have to use the the nutch REST API, and if so, how would I go about this?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way (IMHO) is to use the [Nutch REST API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/Nutch+1.X+RESTAPI), that being said, the REST API doesn't support necessarily all the options supported by the CLI, but perhaps supports enough for your needs. For sure you should be able to trigger new crawls using the API.

Also, we always welcome new contributions to improve any part of Nutch and/or the REST API (in case you find it lacking some feature and would like to contribute back to the project).